# cv is not being installed how do i resolve the following error?

Tags: python, windows, installation, computer-vision

Trying to install `opencv` but faced error.

```
(base) C:\Users\DELL>conda install opencv
```

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initially frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repo data from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initially frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip install python-opencv
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

If you encounter further, check these [details](https://qr.ae/TW24DF).